# ¿Que ocurre en este fragmento de codigo?

Tags: java, java-8, applet, java-awt

Alguien me podria ayudar a entender que es lo que ocurre en este codigo

```
public class unaClase extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
    }
}
```

A mi entender es algo asi como que creo una *clase* de nombre ***unaClase*** que *hereda*(porque se convierte en *hija*) *metodos* y *atributos* de la *clase* ***Applet***; luego se *sobreescribe* al *metodo* ***paint***(que era *heredado* de ***Applet***) y este *metodo* espera recibir un *objeto*(al que le pusimos de nombre ***g***) creado a partir de la clase ***Graphics*** y luego llamamos al *metodo* ***drawRect*** que es propio del *objeto* ***g*** (que se creo a partir de la *clase* ***Graphics***); para que cuando se ejecute la *clase* ***unaClase*** se dibuje un *rectangulo*, ***¿Es asi?***

Comment: Si, es correcto lo que afirmas solo un detalle evita usar Applets que son una clase en desuso en lugar puedes usar JComponent or JPanel si usas swing o  en caso de usar awt usa la clase Canvas

Comment: Si, gracias, Es que queria rectificar algunas cosas que he aprendido sobre POO y este ejemplo en especifico me parecio curioso pues presenta algo que a simple vista puede ser confuso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasan muchas cosas realmente en ese código aunque no lo parezca.

```
public class unaClase extends Applet
```

Esta línea te crea una tipo de dato llamado `unaClase`, que hereda todas las caracteristicas y métodos de una clase padre llamada `java.applet.Applet` que a su vez hereda  características de una clase que se llama `java.awt.Panel`, que a su vez hereda de una clase llamada `java.awt.Container`, que a su vez hereda de una clase llamada `java.awt.Component` que hereda de `java.lang.Object` (Object para los cuates).

Así que para crear una instancia de tipo `unaClase`, deberás crear primero todos los padres para poderle pasar sus propiedades y referencias a métodos.

En el caso de

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
```

estás redefiniendo la funcionalidad de un método que viene de la clase `java.awt.Container`, que recibe un objeto de tipo `java.awt.Graphics` que es en sí una maravilla, pues contiene la información de tu contexto gráfico y las referencias a métodos nativos de tu sistema operativo para realizar las rutinas de pintado y detección, motivo por el cual al llamar a

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
```

le delegas a esa clase la tarea de modificar el contexto gráfico para agregar un rectángulo con el color que tuviera ya detectado.

Ese contexto gráfico es algo muy importante, ya que puede tratarse de un CRT, una pantalla LED, o incluso algo más abstracto como es el caso de un navegador web, y para todos los casos funciona el mismo código; ese es el poder de la abstracción.

Algo que quiero hacer notar es que tu Applet esparte del `Abstract Web Toolkit` o AWT, y en ningún momento en tu código usaste Swing.
Swing tiene su propia especialización llamada JApplet optimizada especialmente para trabajar con Swing.

Otra forma de usar en la actualidad un Applet es usar la clase [JMainFrame](https://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/com/sun/j3d/utils/applet/JMainFrame.html) que se encarga de ponerle un Wrapper para embeberlo en un frame.

Comment: Gracias, ¿entonces con la primera linea no estoy creando una clase como tal?

Comment: Estás definiendo una clase de objetos, es decir un tipo de datos. Eso son las clases. Cuando creas en memoria un objeto de ese tipo de dato se llama instanciar y en tu código no lo haces.